# Adding a new drive for email server

Tags: mount, email, postfix, dovecot

I have installed email server with "dovecot, postfix, postfixadmin" etc. Now I mounted new driver. All my mails are in folder `/home/vmail/` user is: **vmail uid=5000 gid=500**.

I like to move those files to new mounted drive. What is the right way to do it? Making symbolic link to `/media/emaildrive` from `/home/vmail` or configure postfix and dovecot to use `/media/emaildrive/vmail`?

Answer (score 1):

`cp -Rp /home/vmail /mnt/newdrive

mv /home/vmail /home/vmailbackup`
edit fstab to mount the new drive at /home/vmail
`init 6`
done

should work appropriately...